# Dealing with unstable connections with SSH?

Tags: ssh, wireless-networking

I'm on a bit of a travel binge at the moment, and unfortunately that finds me using some of the worse WI-FI connections I've ever seen; periodic disappearance and reappearance, highly variable throughput, etc.

I can deal with that on the web-browser side, but a lot of my work is done over ssh. I already use screen to maintain persistent processes once I make the first hop, and can quickly resume work after the first-hop connection dies, but is there anything I can do with this first hop ssh connection to let it cope more gracefully with spotty connections?

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this issue and tried searching for it.
I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641373/3378531) on StackOverflow.

[Mosh](https://mosh.org/) mentioned in the answer works like a charm. Just keep in mind you'll need to install mosh on both server and client and then enjoy :)

Instead of using ssh, using mosh should help here as it doesn't break connection even on an unstable connection

PS: I know this question is really old but writing it here, in case someone stumbles over it in search of a solution.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the relevant information here please? Thanks :)

Comment: I feel the answer is explanatory enough. I have modified it a bit but let me know if you feel we can add some other information.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only the link-layer of the connection that is sloppy, you could disable KeepAlive and give your connection a better chance to recover from long stalls. This may not work well if you are behind NAT or get assigned changing addresses.

In the generic case, I find it simpler to just use a VPN such as OpenVPN. All the applications running on the static internal address become oblivious to disconnection problems.